# Changed router ip accidently. Can't change it back

Tags: router, ip

My router ip was 192.168.1.1; I changed it to 192.168.1.107 at the router web interface. Now I know that was bad idea. How could I change it back as it was? I can't access web interface now

Comment: Have you tried accessing the web interface at 192.168.1.107?

Answer (score 6):

Visit `http://192.168.1.107` and log in?

You may have to refresh your network connection on the client (release and renew its IP address) first.

Comment: Be sure to release and renew the IP of the device you use to access the router at the new address

Comment: Rebooting the computer should also work for refreshing the routing table, and may be easier if the OP isn't tech-savvy. Still, there's nothing really magical about IP addresses that makes 192.168.y.z any more special than 192.168.c.d.

Answer (score 1):

If I knew the make and model of your router, I'd show you a specific picture of the back of your router... or a picture of the reset button.  But, I can't get that specific.  So, I'll be generic.

[image]

Image courtesy of TigerDirect.com

Now, not every router has a reset button that is so easy to access. Others have only a small hole that gives you access to it.  Either way, examine your router, find the reset button, and push it for 10-15 seconds with the router plugged in.  Then, treat it as if you just got it brand new.  You can even follow the instructions in the manual for how to access it and set it up again.  Chances are, if the default IP address for it was 192.168.1.1 and you had just used it before, it will once again be set to the same.